# Ubuntu MATE 16.04 shutdown delayed

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-mate

I have noticed that my computer shuts down a lot longer than expected.
I decided to enable verbose in GRUB (i.e. disabled `splash` and `quiet` options), and found out that these two prolong the shutdown process by up to 90 seconds:

```
(1 of 2) A stop job is running for monitor and control system power state (XXs / 1min30s)
(2 of 2) A stop job is running for Make remote CUPS printers available locally (XXs / 1min30s)
```

I'd want to know if there's a way to skip these processes, without harming my computer.
I tried powering my computer off with the Shutdown button (in 15 seconds), but doing that is both tedious and risky, so I'm looking for an alternative on how to shut it down quicker without harming my data.

I'm running an Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS version:
Here's the complete version of the kernel:

```
$ uname -a
Linux **** 4.4.0-21-generic #37-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 18:33:37 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Thanks.

Comment: The system is waiting for those stop jobs to complete, if they take too long (longer than the specified time, though sometimes the time can be infinite, luckily in your case this is not the case) they are stopped and the shutdown process continues, there's not really much else one can do or really should do. Except perhaps make it wait less time before killing them. Though they seem to be important things so I'd just wait. I mean, my machine takes 30 minutes sometimes to shut down or it never does, so 3 minutes max is really nothing I'd worry about... Unless it's taking longer than that?

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's just best to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$ shutdown now`

I had the same issue as you. My Ubuntu Mate 16.04 also takes some times to shutdown, like 30-40 seconds using the GUI. Usually it is just much faster, like 5 secs, if it's done via the terminal.

I still don't know why, I am guessing that the terminal way just forces everything to stop/kills everything and shuts down. I haven't found out why. Maybe some other people could shed a light as to why.